# Hover over multiple buttons in Java?

Tags: java, button, multidimensional-array, awt

Is it possible, in Java, when you hover over a single button, to make the program think you are hovering over multiple buttons?
I'm using a multi-dimensional array with buttons and want to be able to have 5 buttons be hovered over at a time. (All the buttons near the actual hover).

Any ideas on how to do this?

Note: I'm not using JButtons, just regular buttons. (awt.Button)

**EDIT**
I obviously wasn't clear enough, and I apologize for that.
Here is a screenshot of what I'm looking for:

[image: Hover]

So, the cursor is hovering over the first gray space, and all of the space next to it have a different background, however, they are not considered as being hovered over, which if what I need.

Comment: So you really mean "in Swing," right?

Comment: Um, wouldn't Swing be using JButtons?

Comment: Then what in tarnation are you using? Or is it supposed to be a secret?

Comment: I've only imported awt.Button. And I'm just using regular buttons, not Jbuttons, is that really so confusing? o0

Comment: This could be AWT, SWT, android, or lord knows what else.  It's only confusing if we can't read minds.

Comment: So you want to have the 4 buttons following the one your mouse hovers over in some sort of selected state?

Comment: Yes! I have it so the background color is changed, but I'd prefer a state change of some sort!

Comment: @Johannes the hovered over looks like the focus which you can check with a focus listener. The focus itself is limited to one component in a Window so you would have to model any additional state yourself. (Disclaimer my knowledge about awt is rather limited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `MouseListener`, when the `mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)` method is called on the master button, explicitly call the same method on all of the listeners of all of the other buttons, passing the event you have been given. Ditto for the `mouseExited(MouseEvent e)` method.

It's up to you to maintain a reference from the master button to the subordinate buttons.

The subordinate buttons' listeners will receive an event that refers to the master button. If necessary, create your listeners with a reference to the button that they are attached to, so that you can operate on that button when receiving an event.

EDIT:

This is the kind of thing I'm talking about. Does it help?

```
final List<Button> subordinateButtons = Arrays.asList(new Button(), new Button(), new Button());
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        for (Button subordinateButton : subordinateButtons) {
            subordinateButton.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        for (Button subordinateButton : subordinateButtons) {
            subordinateButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

});
```

There's no reason why you can't keep a reference from a `MouseListener` to a `List<Button>`. If it's the business of the listener to work on those buttons then design your classes so that it happens.

Comment: `mouseMoved` should be forwarded, too.